# Can't load Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android

Real beginner's question:
My university group are working on an Android project. We're hosting it on an repository. I tried to download a version but I can't get it working.

I have Eclipse 32Bit installed, with the latest version of the JDK. I have the Android SDK Manager installed, with Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools, Android 4.2.2(API 17), Android 4.1.2(API 16) and all the extras installed.

To begin with, I was getting an error "Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties." I did this but it didn't fix anything. I found an alternative fix on Google which suggested I right click the project and go to properties. Then, go to Java Compiler, choose Enable Project Specific Settings and choose a lower compliance level. I did this and set it to 1.6.

I've read that something could be missed from the Android Manifest but I honestly don't know what. This is a copy of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.csc7045project"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.csc7045project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.csc7045project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.csc7045project.EventActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCvdEysH-5FQeiNDiiXFBd25iZLtZYIdUY"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

In the main code of the project, the issue all seems to resolve around GoogleMaps. There is a variable GoogleMap map, and all references to the variable map in the code are errors. I do have the Google APIs downloaded through the SDK Manager.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to fix it so I can start to contribute. Additionally, I should point out at this stage that the project does work on other machines, so it's not an error with the code.

Edit: When I run, I get the following 18 errors (some of these errors are repeated multiple times):

```
CameraUpdateFactory cannot be resolved
CameraUpdateFactory cannot be resolved
GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type
LatLng cannot be resolved to a type
MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type
Marker cannot be resolved to a type
MarkerOptions cannot be resolved to a type
OnMarkerClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

Edit 2:

[image: Edit 2: Screenshot of Project Folder added]

Comment: You forgot to add `</manifest>` at the end of your xml file. But I think it's more an error like copy/paste

Comment: Copy and paste error - I've added it in now. Thanks.

Comment: @blackbelt deleted since 3 minutes

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Can't you just add the project to a workspace? Or the project doesn't compile? Or maybe you can't deploy it on a device? Or the application crashes on a device?

Comment: If the project works on other machines, did you try to see what are the differences between your configuration and their ? Maybe you forgot to install some stuff

Comment: When I click run it just says your project contains errors. Those are all contained on the GoogleMap references. I can post the whole file if it will help.

Comment: Did you include the Maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

Comment: I think I have (towards bottom of Manifest above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you receive it seems like you handled you first problem:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7'
```

now you problem is derived from the fact that classes that are related to Google Map API V2 can't be found by the compiler. this problem will occur when you don't perform the Google Map API V2 referencing correctly.

please head to this guide I wrote on how to properly integrate Google Maps in your application and follow the first three steps to get an idea of how it's done correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: I had actually seen your guide before and followed it to a tee. Unfortunately, nothing changed. All the code that was needed along with the libraries and dependencies were already in the project.

Comment: could you add a screen shot of your project dependencies folder?

Comment: Picture added to main question

Comment: weird, for some reason Eclipse ignores your import. If you expand the google-play-services library do you see your needed files under the maps package? Try to create a new project and make the process again to see if the imports work. If you click your project with the right click and go to properties > Android. in the lower part do you see the library referenced with a green v?

Comment: The google-play-service_lib.jar just has an android package with an UnusedStub.class file in it. The google-play-service.jar has a whole clatter of packages, including maps which has all the things I was getting errors on (e.g. camera update, googlemap, location source).

Comment: Additionally, if I right click the project and go to Properties-Android, the library is indeed green.

Comment: Your configuration look OK then, Please try to create a new project and perform all the process again. I would try to download the google-play-service again from the SDK Manager and maybe move it to a place where it path would be as short as possible (stumbled upon errors because of this)

Comment: I created a new project and copied the files from the existing project across. Now, when I right click on the errors I get the option to import the relevant libraries. Doing this has appeared to solve all the problems. I'm not sure what was going wrong in the first place. IT worries me a little as we're trying to do our work over a repository. Hopefully me fixing this on my machine doesn't break it for someone else. Still, THANK YOU!

Comment: You welcome, it's some times happens with Eclipse, error for no reason.

Comment: Yeah. I'll keep debugging this program. It now runs, but on both emulator and real device the map doesn't actually show. The little icon so show your location is in the top right corner and the zoom in and out are visible, but its just grey. I'll keep working away at it!

Comment: the problem you describe right now is not connected to the one you had before, this problem happens usually when you don't generate or register the api key properly. read the key guide in my blog and make sure you follow all it's steps. And if my answer helped you, you might want to upvote/accept it.

Comment: Out of curiosity - I followed your guide to generate a key, but still can't get the maps working. I'll keep trying to fix it, but how does this work when the app is being shared across multiple machines the way our group are doing it? Do we not all need different keys?

Comment: The google API key is connected directly to the SHA1 key that sits in your computer. So for your question the answer is yes. each person who works on this project should generate his own key using his own SHA1 key in the dubug.keystore.